# Is it possible to get notification outside of PyCharm console if my program crashes?

Tags: python, notifications, pycharm

So I have a program which are working in PyCharm for a long time and sometimes it crashes. And after it I get some logs in its console. However it isn't convenient to check it every 10 minutes, so is it possible to get some notifications on my display outside PyCharm when my program has crashed? Maybe some sound or pop-up window or somthing else...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\a` character to make an "ASCII Bell", which can either make an alert sound or be reconfigured by the OS to make a visual notification.

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def notify():
    # Python 2: print "\a"
    # or from __future__ import print_function
    # at the top of your code
    print("\a")

# Let's crash
1/0
```

Note that with `atexit`, the `notify` function won't run when exiting to interactive mode (the `-i` flag when starting Python). It will though, when you exit with `exit()`/`quit()`, `Ctrl-Z`, or `Ctrl-C`, an exception, or reaching the end of code.